# Thread when confirming invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

when creating invoice I want to add it to the thread if there is more than 17 invoice_lines

```py
        @api.multi
        def _run_threaded_invoice(self, ):
            with Environment.manage():
                new_cr = self.pool.cursor()
                self = self.with_env(self.env(cr=new_cr))
                self.action_invoice_open()
                new_cr.commit()
                new_cr.close()


    @api.multi
    def action_invoice_open(self):
        thread = False
        if self.type == 'in_invoice' and len(self.invoice_line_ids) > 17 and thread == False:
            thread = True
            threaded_calculation = threading.Thread(
                target=self._run_threaded_invoice)
            threaded_calculation.start()



           #and other logic that i have added to this method
```

but i do get errors

```
TransactionRollbackError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

PoolError: The Connection Pool Is Full
```

this looks very familiar to me as recursion error...

how do i set up thread correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's recursive use context to prevent from repeating the same operation

```py
@api.multi
def _run_threaded_invoice(self, ):
    with Environment.manage():
        new_cr = self.pool.cursor()
        self = self.with_env(self.env(cr=new_cr))
        # add the key to the context
        self.with_context(is_in_thread=True).action_invoice_open()
        new_cr.commit()
        new_cr.close()




@api.multi
def action_invoice_open(self):
    is_in_thread = self.env.context('is_in_thread', False)
    if not is_in_thread and self.type == 'in_invoice' and len(self.invoice_line_ids) > 17:
        threaded_calculation = threading.Thread(
            target=self._run_threaded_invoice)
        threaded_calculation.start()
        return True # Let the thread do the job

    # this logic is execute by the new thread if > 17 or the main thread  <17   
    .......
    .......
    ......
```